# bash expand to last folder in directory

Tags: bash, shell, expand

Is there a way to specify the "last folder in the directory" for a path?

For example, I have a directory `a/` containing folders `1/`, `2/`, `3/`, `4/`, `5/`.

How can I specify `cat a/${last_folder}/<my file>`? In this case, it should expand to `a/5/<my file>`.

Comment: How do you define last folder? Is it alphabetically last?

Comment: I guess its the deepest node/dir.. instead of last node. please chng the language if possible. +1 for the question. check this here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27021/how-to-name-a-file-in-the-deepest-level-of-a-directory-tree

Comment: yes, alphabetically last.

Answer (score 5):

[Subshell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) is your friend.

```
cat "$(find a/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 |sort |tail -1)"/<my file>
```

Or if you want to be obscurantist with it:

```
: a/*/
cat "$_"/<my file>
```

`:` is a command that does nothing. It's used here to set `$_` to the last word expansion in the command line. Since `a/*/` expands to `a/1 a/2 a/3 a/4 a/5`, it sets `$_` to `a/5`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what OP meant for +1 for the 2nd part of the answer.

Comment: I like the `: a/*/` method.  I wonder how we can assert that at least one directory exists.